# iOS: display time as am/pm

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime

I am new to objective c. I wish to do the following:
Convert 24 hour format to 12 hour and then add +2 to hour and display it like: 4:00 pm
I get the 12 hour format but after adding +2 to it , the time is displayed always as "am", i.e even if it is 4 pm it is displayed as 4 am. Below is my code:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
timeFormatter.dateFormat=@"hh:00 a";
NSString  *currentHour=[timeFormatter stringFromDate:now ];
lblcurrentHour.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentHour];
NSLog(@"%@",currentHour);

int hour=[[timeFormatter stringFromDate:now]intValue];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:00",hour+=3]];

dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
lblnextHour.text = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date1]; // prints 4:00 am not pm
```

How do i solve this? Where am i getting wrong?

Comment: timeFormatter.dateFormat=@"hh:00 a"; ?????? 00 ?? should mm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you want to take the current time and display the minutes as :00, anchoring to the current hour.  Then you want to add two hours and display that time.  The following code prints 04:00 AM and 06:00 AM to the console (local time is 0421.)

For calendrical calculations, I would avoid using `NSDateFormatter` as you are doing when you compute the time two hours from now.  There are too many ways that can go astray.  For example, what happens when the *now* time is 2300?

A good reference on calendrical calculations in Cocoa is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        //  use gregorian calendar for calendrical calculations
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        //  get current date
        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendarUnit units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
        units |= NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *currentComponents = [gregorian components:units fromDate:date];

        //  change the minutes to 0
        currentComponents.minute = 0;
        date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:currentComponents];

        //  format and display the time
        NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm a";
        NSString *currentTimeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        NSLog(@"Current hour = %@",currentTimeString);

        //  add two hours
        NSDateComponents *incrementalComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        incrementalComponents.hour = 2;
        NSDate *twoHoursLater = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:incrementalComponents toDate:date options:0];

        //  format and display new time
        NSString *twoHoursLaterStr = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:twoHoursLater];
        NSLog(@"Two hours later = %@",twoHoursLaterStr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSLog(@"Today's Date and Time: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Output:

> Today's Date and Time: 02:43:33 PM